# ng-boostrap removed all bootstrap styles

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 was applied to the app, i have tried to apply ng-boostrap by following https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started but all styles of the page have gone as no style has been applied.

What is shown on the page:

[image: What is shown]

**Update:**
It works fine if uninstall Bootstrap 4 and install bootstrap 3, seems something need to be changed in the app for Bootstrap 4 be applied, what changes shuld be applied to the app to make it works with Bootstrap4?

Comment: gone means , did you check the elements are they overridden ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are properly including Bootstrap 4 CSS? ng-bootstrap is replacing JS part of Bootstrap package but you still need CSS!

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource This is in my styles of angular-cli.json: "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css". however it is not mention as requied in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: @RahulSingh no bootstrap style is applied as you can see in the attached image.

Comment: can you check your node modules if you have bootstrap there . you need to install it like `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` i hope you had used the `save` command

Comment: @mehran you are missing CSS. You need Bootstrap 4 CSS (Bootstrap 3 CSS is not compatible with ng-bootstrap). And the https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started clearly states that you _need_ dependency on Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: @RahulSingh I have followed that exactly as mention in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: according to @pkozlowski.opensource if you need bootstrap v4. then install like this npm i bootstrap-v4-dev --save

Comment: If you want support for bootstrap 3, have a look at ngx-bootstrap instead. They support both v.3 and v.4: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap

Comment: Back to bootstrap 3, seems to be fine. I needed bootstrap compatible date picker at the first place. does ngx-bootstrap support date picker?